# Why does this event handler use "e = e || event"?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, cross-browser, dom-events

Can someone explain me what does this line of code means:

```
function(e) { e = e || event; e.returnValue = false; return false; }
```

Why is the parameter named `e`?
If I change it to 'myparam' will it work?
What does `e = e` mean?

Where is the variable `event` ( after `||` ) declared ?
What is `e.returnValue?`

Comment: Remember to ask one question at a time. And search first.

Comment: It is one question. The others are just to clarify the meaning of the very question!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is all basic event management, although it is missing `e.preventDefault()`...

To break it down, when an event handler is fired:

- Some browsers pass a parameter to the callback holding event data (this is the standards-compliant way of doing it)
- Other browsers (mostly old IE) instead put the event data in `window.event` (which is accessed here with just `event`, which is risky since that relies on there being no local variable with that name)

Next, `e = e || event;` is a standard way of saying "if the parameter was not passed, default it to whatever's after the `||`". In this case, if the event parameter is not passed, then it looks for the global variable.

`e.returnValue` is one of three ways to stop an event from causing its default action. The other two are `e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault()` (which is conspicuously absent from the code you posted), and `return false;`

Answer (score 5):

This line is just to make IE8 and below function the same way as all other browsers. All other browsers pass the target element (`e`) to the event function.

So what this piece of code does is:

If `e` exists, keep `e`.  If it doesn't exist, you are using an older version of IE and we assign the `windows.event` object to `e`.  Now all browsers behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code test if an `e` object exists, else use the object `event` and assign it to e. After that it sets the attribute `returnValue` to false and returns false.

**This is code which runs on IE and other browsers the same way, no matter if the event object is called `e` or `event`.**

Comment: I find "set it to e" ambiguous - which way is the assignment going? Perhaps "assign it to e" would be clearer...